# Android Studio - How to add a Screen Size Definition

Tags: android-studio

I am building an Android Application using Android Studio.

I want my layout to be as precise as possible, however, it seems that the list of Android Virtual Devices where we can render the layout to is limited to Nexus Devices as shown in this screenshot below:

[image: Device List]

and the "Generic Phones and Tablets" do not have much screen size and resolution variety, so I decided to add my device definition as such:

[image: My Device]

However, it did not appear in the devices that Android Studio can render a layout to in the `Design` view of a layout.

### Solved

After restarting Android Studio, the newly created AVD (Samsung Galaxy Note 1) now appeared in my list of devices that I can preview the rendering to when I view my layout.

I think all I had to do was to restart Android Studio for it to appear. It works now.

Comment: Please have a look at Genymotion!. Since using it, my Android dev life has been much better.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue, restarting Android Studio fixed it.

Comment: Had the same problem, and restarting fixed it. Why don't you convert this into an answer?

Comment: Hello, in the future please **do not post** the answer in the question section. Use the **answers section** for that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution to this, is to restart Android Studio. The new devices should appear at the bottom of the list.

Comment: This is correct answer, i also needed to restart studio.

Comment: Usually when you create AVD its not getting reflected immediately inside Custom screen list. So as to start reflecting your device you need to restart Android Studio and check inside custom screen list

Answer (score 0):

For others having similar issues, you may want to check the API level of your AVDs vs the compileSDK of your project.  I've found that, at least for Wear OS AVDs, my devices that target an earlier API don't show up.  Once I made them the same as my compile SDK version, they showed up.